# Using setInterval() to make a session timer with ReactJS hooks: error messages, irregular counting and "null" output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm trying to make a timer that will start (at 00:00) when the user loads the Home page, increment every second, and reset to 00:00 when they go to a different page.

Here's my newest code:

```
  const [ timerCount, increaseTimer ] = useState(0);

  function timerItself() {
    function timerIncrement() {
      var currentTimerCount = timerCount;
      increaseTimer(currentTimerCount + 1);
    };
    setInterval(() => timerIncrement, 1000);
    clearInterval(timerIncrement);
    return;
  }

  function pageHome() {
    var timerMinutes = JSON.stringify(Math.floor(timerItself / 60));
    var timerSeconds = JSON.stringify(timerItself % 60);

    timerItself();

    return (
      <div classname="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Hello world!</h1>
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>{timerMinutes.padStart(2, '0')}:{timerSeconds.padStart(2, '0')}</p>
          <p>
            <button onClick={(() => changePage('About'))}>
              About
            </button>
            <button onClick={(() => changePage('Help'))}>
              Help
            </button>
          </p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Previously I had wrapped the `setInterval()` in a `const` like so:
`const timer = setInterval(() => increaseTimer(timerCount + 1), 1000);` and tried putting `clearInterval()` in the buttons' onClick functions thinking this would just reset the timer.

The output had weird behaviour: the timer would count up at irregular intervals, starting very slow from 00:03 instead of 00:00 and becoming very fast. The sequence of times shown was consistent but I couldn't recognise it as a mathematical sequence: 3, 7, 11, 29... 81... and reaching very high numbers within about 30 seconds. Couldn't figure out where in the code the numbers were coming from.

I did some more reading and came to the conclusion that `timer` was setting off more than one timer at the same time and somehow adding their outputs together. So I wrote `timerItself()` instead, with a `clearInterval()` in there which I assumed would also fire every second to clear the old timer and clean up for the new one. But now there's no counting going on at all, and the stringified output from the timer is "null:null".

I'm confused over where the `clearInterval()` should even go, as I think that's the main key to this problem. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Because your call to initialize the interval is at the top level of your component you are adding a new interval on every render and triggering a render on every tick, so you very quickly have an exponential number of intervals all triggering new renders. You should instead wrap the setInterval in a useEffect and clear it before unmount at the end of each render cycle. see: [React Timer using functional Hooks | Timer is not stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291293/react-timer-using-functional-hooks-timer-is-not-stopping/68291421#68291421)

Comment: Finally got it working, thanks for your help! Also turned out I had to use ```if (page == 'Home')``` instead of ```if (page == PageHome)``` in useEffect for the counting to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

This code is working well for my purposes:

```
  const [ timer, changeTimer ] = useState(0);
  var currentTimerCount = timer;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (page !== 'Home')
      changeTimer(0);
    if (page == 'Home')
      currentTimerCount = setInterval(() => {changeTimer(prevTimer => prevTimer + 1)}, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(currentTimerCount);
  });

  var timerMinutes = JSON.stringify(Math.floor(currentTimerCount / 60));
  var timerSeconds = JSON.stringify(currentTimerCount % 60);
```

and then calling timerMinutes and timerSeconds as before.

Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 0):

To create an interval that start when you render a component, you can use useEffect Hook, with your timerCount as a dependency. Because when you first render the component you want to start the counter, and as you increment the timer you want the interval to keep going.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [timerCount, increaseTimer] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let myTimerId;

    myTimerId = setInterval(() => {
      increaseTimer(timerCount + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(myTimerId);
  }, [timerCount]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Timer {timerCount}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}


export function Other() {
  return <div>This is the other Page</div>;
}
```

The arrow function returned by the useEffect Hook is a cleanup function that will clearTheInterval to prevent a memory leak.

And here is the App.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home, { Other } from './Home';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/other">Other</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/other" component={Other} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

I used a library called react-router-dom to navigate between paths on your app, without making a new request.

Reference : https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

And

useEffect : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

// Also I suggest you to name the function that updates the state in such manner :

```
const [myExampleState, setMyExampleState] = useState('Example1');

setMyExampleState('Example2');
```

- Hope I helped. ( Also check out the lifecycle to understand better how React works ;D )

Comment: I omitted the [ page, changePage ] bits from my post just to make it simpler to read the timer part. I had read about react-router-dom but decided to simply render the pages via my own function components and ```if``` statements as I'm not bothered about changing the url and wanted to explore vanilla React functionality more. Thanks for your answer tho!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah setinterval doesn't play well with hooks.  Even with the useEffect solution you'll lose time. If the interval is up to 3/4ths of a second, a rerender for any reason will destroy and recreate the timer back at zero again. Lots of rerenders,  spaced out, effectively paralyze the timer.

This might be a good case to put the timer outside of the component. It's still in scope for the component without being controlled by it. Same for whatever function that's called on nav away.