# React count down timers with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setinterval

First let me show some relevant code before I explain my problem

CountDownTimer component

```
import { FC, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

interface CountDownTimerProps {
  defaultMinutes: number;
  defaultSeconds: number;
  ticking: boolean;
}

const CountDownTimer: FC<CountDownTimerProps> = (props) => {
  const { defaultMinutes, defaultSeconds, ticking } = props;
  const [[mins, secs], setTime] = useState([defaultMinutes, defaultSeconds]);

  const timerId = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);

  const stopTimerInterval = () => timerId.current !== null && clearInterval(timerId.current);

  const tick = () => {
    if (mins === 0 && secs === 0) {
      return;
    } else if (secs === 0) {
      setTime([mins - 1, 59]);
    } else {
      setTime([mins, secs - 1]);
    }
  };

  const reset = () => {
    stopTimerInterval();
    setTime([defaultMinutes, defaultSeconds]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ticking) {
      reset();
      return;
    } else {
      timerId.current = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
      console.log("creating interval");
    }

    return () => {
      stopTimerInterval();
    };
  });

  return (
    <p className="text-white text-5xl">{`${mins.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${secs
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}`}</p>
  );
};

export default CountDownTimer;
```

PomodoroClock component

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { buildStyles, CircularProgressbarWithChildren } from "react-circular-progressbar";
import CountDownTimer from "./CountDownTimer";
import MinusIcon from "./MinusIcon";
import PlusIcon from "./PlusIcon";

interface PomodoroClockProps {
  ticking: boolean;
  mins: number;
  onIncrementClock(): any;
  onDecrementClock(): any;
}

const PomodoroClock: FC<PomodoroClockProps> = (props) => {
  const { mins, ticking, onDecrementClock, onIncrementClock } = props;

  return (
    <div className="w-96 h-96 bg-red-400 rounded-full">
      <CircularProgressbarWithChildren
        value={47}
        strokeWidth={4}
        styles={buildStyles({
          trailColor: "#fff",
          pathColor: "#EF4444",
        })}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
          <button onClick={onDecrementClock}>
            <MinusIcon />
          </button>
          <CountDownTimer defaultMinutes={mins} defaultSeconds={0} ticking={ticking} />
          <button onClick={onIncrementClock}>
            <PlusIcon />
          </button>
        </div>
      </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PomodoroClock;
```

App component

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";
import PomodoroClock from "./PomodoroClock";

const App: FC = () => {
  const [ticking, setTicking] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [mins, setMins] = useState<number>(5);

  const toggleTicking = () => setTicking(!ticking);

  const toggleButtonText = ticking ? "STOP" : "START";

  type updateClockKind = "inc" | "dec";
  const updateClockTime = (kind: updateClockKind, by: number) => {
    if (kind === "inc" && mins + by < 20) {
      setMins(mins + by);
    } else if (kind === "dec" && mins - by > 0) {
      setMins(mins - by);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex content-center flex-col items-center gap-8">
      <PomodoroClock
        mins={mins}
        ticking={ticking}
        onIncrementClock={() => updateClockTime("inc", 5)}
        onDecrementClock={() => updateClockTime("dec", 5)}
      />
      <button
        className="bg-red-500 py-4 px-6 rounded-lg text-white text-2xl"
        onClick={toggleTicking}
      >
        {toggleButtonText}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

SO currently, when I press the start button on the clock everything seems to be working correct it counts down and when I press stop it resets. BUT the problem im having is that on every tick of the clock its creating a new interval and when I stop the clock its erroring in the console with thousands of `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded`

Any help is appreciated, it is probably just something small but I have been stuck on this for some time. thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Timer using functional Hooks | Timer is not stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291293/react-timer-using-functional-hooks-timer-is-not-stopping)

Comment: Specifically from @pilchard's linked answer, you are missing a dependency array on `useEffect`. If you had [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) installed, it would complain and offer to add exhaustive effect deps automatically.